# zz_moto_actionbar_bkg.xml resource error on Droid

Tags: android, crash-reports

I am getting strange crash reports from Droid X and Droid Pro.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
File res/drawable/zz_moto_actionbar_bkg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x10803a8
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1735)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:596)
    at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7542)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setBackground(AlertController.java:719)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:424)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:232)
    at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:251)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:307)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:225)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
    at com.*******.a(SourceFile:320)
    at com.*******.onOptionsItemSelected(SourceFile:292)
    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2251)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:809)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:553)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9089)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.addLayer(LayerDrawable.java:186)
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:157)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:795)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:736)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1732)
    ... 27 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.addLayer(LayerDrawable.java:186)
    at android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable.inflate(LayerDrawable.java:157)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:795)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:736)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1732)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:596)
    at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:7542)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setBackground(AlertController.java:719)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:424)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:232)
    at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:251)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:307)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:225)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
    at com.*******.a(SourceFile:320)
    at com.*******.onOptionsItemSelected(SourceFile:292)
    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2251)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:809)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:553)
    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9089)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It happens when launching an alert dialog. Of course I am not using any resource like that, and Only resource I am using on `AlertDialog` is `android.R.drawable.ic_input_add`.

I tried some search on this, but the only relevant page I found was https://supportforums.motorola.com/message/513190 and it does not help much.

Have anyone else had a similar problem or found a solution for this?

Comment: Did you by chance find a solution to this?  I'm seeing the error as well, but it's on the Droid RAZR.  I'm thinking that Motorola has created their own AlertDialog class to override the stock AlertDialog, and it's conflicting somehow.

Comment: @hooked82 unfortunately no. I have kind of given up at this point.

Comment: If it's of any reassurance I too have started encountering this.  Mine is on some instructions I pop up with an alert view but not sure if it's 100% reproducible yet.(Motorola Droid X / Shadow  on Verizon running Android 2.3.3)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We hit this same bug and, at least in our case, it turned out to be due to running out of memory while an image associated with that layout was being loaded. The layout itself seems to be some skinning stuff Motorola is doing for the alert dialog (my assumption). The only way I found out it was an OutOfMemoryError is that our QA tester generated an adb bugreport when he hit the crash and I could see the OutOfMemoryError in the bugreport caused while attempting to decode an image (on the same thread on which the stack trace was generated).

Comment: `zz_moto` assets are all part of Motorola's themeing. I like your suggestion it's really an OutOfMemoryError.

Answer (score 1):

Motorola phones are so annoying and sometimes can be spainful.
I used to have current location icon not showing up on the google map only with motorola phones. They fixed the issue on ICS upgrade so all the efforts and time I spent to figure out the problem went to trash.
And now I'm having this exactly the same issue with some users when alert dialog is opened.
And the worst part is I can't reproduce this with the same phone, the same OS the user reported the bug.

Answer (score -2):

you try this type code in alert dialog

```
{
myDialog = new Dialog(context);
myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.addfence_dialog);
myDialog.setTitle("EditFence");
myDialog.setCancelable(true);

strTitle = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_dialog_edtTitle);
strArea = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_dialog_edtArea);
strDescription = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_dialog_edtDescription);
strTag = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_dialog_edtTag);

save = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_dialog_btnSave);
cancel = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.add_dialog_btnCancel);

strTitle.setText(getTitle);
strArea.setText(getArea);
strDescription.setText(getDesc);
strTag.setText(getTag);

save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
          .....
}
myDialog.show();
}
```